# Lodash 'get' not working when use in a Arrow Function (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I'm using `Lodash` in a project and I'm trying to use the `get` function in order to filter some data to activate a button to save some data to an endpoint, but when I use the `get` inside of an Arroe Function it returns `undefined`, then I use the same code in a variable assignation works properly, you can check the error in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pfw7iq). Someone else getting this kind of error? Thanks in advance.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const checkMandatory = tab => {
    get(this.state.data, [tab, 'data', 'datosCalculados'], []);
  };
  const obligatorios = checkMandatory('ingresos');
  const obligatorios2 = get(this.state.data, ['ingresos', 'data', 'datosCalculados'], []);
  console.log('Obligatorios: ', obligatorios);
  console.log('Obligatorios2: ', obligatorios2);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return` was missing

Instead of

```
const checkMandatory = tab => {
  get(this.state.data, [tab, 'data', 'datosCalculados'], []);
};
```

do

```
const checkMandatory = tab => { 
  return get(this.state.data, [tab, 'data', 'datosCalculados'], []); 
};
```

or better yet:

```
const checkMandatory = tab => get(this.state.data, [tab, 'data', 'datosCalculados'], []);
```

resulting in:

[image]

Comment: True, I could also delete de `{}` and it would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My error was not returning the value on the `checkMandatory` validator function, to solve it:

```
const checkMandatory = tab => get(this.state.data, [tab, 'data', 'datosCalculados'], []);
```